# Can't send data to Delegate

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mvvm, uikit

I'll try to get the data of an API of Pokemon using MVVM, I used my MainViewModel to perform the request, if I print the pokemon array in the MainViewModel I get the array but when I send the array to the delegate I can't show the array in the MainViewDelegate.
Regards.

When I print the data in MainViewModel I get the data like this.

```json
[Pokemon.PokemonModel(name: "bulbasaur", imageURL: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"), Pokemon.PokemonModel(name: "ivysaur", imageURL: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"), Pokemon.PokemonModel(name: "venusaur", imageURL: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/")]
```

```
//  MainViewController.swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray6

        setUpView()
        setUpLayout()
        viewModel.fetchPokemon()
    }
```

```swift
//  MainViewModel.swift
import UIKit

class MainViewModel {
    let pokemonUrl = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=898&offset=0"
    var delegate: MainViewDelegate?

    func getPokemonImage() -> UIImage {
        return UIImage(named: "pikachu")!
    }

    func getTitleButton() -> String {
        return "Pokemon"
    }

    func fetchPokemon() {
        performRequest(with: pokemonUrl)
    }

    private func performRequest(with urlString: String) {
        // 1. Create/get URL
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            // 2. Create URLSession
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            // 3. Give the session a task
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { [self] data, response, error in
                if error != nil {
                    delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                }

                if let safeData = data {
                    if let pokemon = self.parseJSON(pokemonData: safeData) {
                        delegate?.didUpdatePokemon(pokemons: pokemon)
                        print(pokemon)
                    }
                }
            }
            // 4. Start the task
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    private func parseJSON(pokemonData: Data) -> [PokemonModel]? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodeData = try decoder.decode(PokemonData.self, from: pokemonData)
            let pokemon = decodeData.results?.compactMap({
                if let name = $0.name, let imageURL = $0.url {
                    return PokemonModel(name: name, imageURL: imageURL)
                }
                return nil
            })
            return pokemon
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
}
```

```swift
//  MainView+Delegates.swift
import UIKit

// MARK: - Custom Delegates

extension MainViewController: MainViewDelegate {
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

    func didUpdatePokemon(pokemons: [PokemonModel]) {
        print(pokemons)
    }
}


extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    public subscript(safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return (startIndex <= index && index < endIndex) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}

// Get 4 items
extension Collection {
    func choose(_ n: Int) -> Array<Element> {
        Array(shuffled().prefix(n))
    }
}
```

```swift
//
//  MainView+Protocols.swift
//

import Foundation

// MARK: - Que es lo que debe de tener

protocol MainViewDelegate {
    func didUpdatePokemon(pokemons: [PokemonModel])
    func didFailWithError(error: Error)
}
```

```swift
//
//  PokemonData.swift

import UIKit

// MARK: - PokemonData

struct PokemonData: Codable {
    let results: [Result]?
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let url: String?
}
```

```swift
//
//  PokemonModel.swift

import Foundation

struct PokemonModel {
    let name: String
    let imageURL: String
}
```

I try to use a delegate to use the data.

Comment: I do not see where you set the delegate and object us the delegate. May be the view controller but when ? The view controller will have to reload the collection view when called assuming the main view model hold the Pokemon list.

Comment: @PtitXav I use it in the controller only for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view model has an optional delegate property, but (in the code shown) you never set that delegate property to whatever is providing the delegate services.  If this isn't set all calls to the delegate functions will fail but as you are optional chaining them you won't get any failure message back.  As you do actually have valid data printing will work.

When you initialise the view model (which you also don't show!) you need to initialise the 'delegate' property.  You could do this through its initialiser or in 'viewDidLoad` by

```
viewModel.delegate = self
```

which will allow you to call through to the delegate methods.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new in swift and I have all the day trying to solve this.